# Sending custom DTO via ria services

Tags: silverlight, soap, wcf-ria-services

Hi I have class to sen via ria service.
class look like

```
    [DataContract]
public partial class AttributeNode
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int Uid { get; set; }

    public AttributeNode()
    {
        this.Children = new List<String>();
    }

    private String text;

    [DataMember]
    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            this.Uid = text.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    [Include]
    [Association("AttributeNode_AttributeNode", "Uid", "Uid")]
    public List<AttributeNode> Children { get; set; }

    public void AddChild(AttributeNode child)
    {
        this.Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I recive object to client it's not ok. It always as a Children contain itself. Problem is on List of same type. Help?

Tnx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is some kind of parent-child tree structure.

The Association tag is used to say "this key" and "other key".

Your AttributeNode class needs a Id property to tell which its parent.

You'd need

```
[Key]
public int Uid { get; set; }
public int ParentUid { get; set; }


[Include]
[Association("AttributeNode_AttributeNode", "Uid", "ParentUid")]
public List<AttributeNode> Children { get; set; }
```